# How do I revert to a previous git in R studio?

Tags: r, git, github, rstudio

I know similar issues have been addressed in a bunch posts, but I couldn't figure out how to solve this issue anyway.

So, I have synchronized my local directory with this git repo

```
Dario (master *) replicationKumar $ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:DarioBoh/replicationKumar.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:DarioBoh/replicationKumar.git (push)
```

I successfully pushed a few commits, so I am pretty confident I have synchronized everything correctly. 
Also, I ran

```
Dario (master *) replicationKumar $ git pull origin master
From github.com:DarioBoh/replicationKumar
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

which shows that I should be working on a copy of what I have on github.
Since the last commit, I deleted a few files though, and now I would like to recover all them from the remote directory from this commit

```
Dario (master *) replicationKumar $ git log
commit 91a3dfdb30084654a7a5517250d2a70dfddb931b
Author: DarioBoh <bonarettidario@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Jul 19 10:00:12 2016 -0500

    REFACTOR linechart moved from server to chart.R
```

In fact, the local directory currently looks like this

```
Dario (master *) replicationKumar $ ls -a
.           .RData          .Rproj.user     .gitignore
..          .Rhistory       .git            replicationKumar.Rproj
```

I thought `checkout` was gonna do the job and I did

```
Dario (master *) replicationKumar $ git checkout 91a3dfdb30084654a7a5517250d2a70dfddb931b
D   charts.R
D   datasets.R
D   server.R
D   sidebarMenu.R
D   ui.R
D   ui1.R
D   ui2.R
Note: checking out '91a3dfdb30084654a7a5517250d2a70dfddb931b'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 91a3dfd... REFACTOR linechart moved from server to chart.R
```

However, my local directory does not show the files present in the checked out commit as I would expect

```
Dario ((91a3dfd...) *) replicationKumar $ ls -a
.           .Rhistory       .gitignore
..          .Rproj.user     FETCH_HEAD
.RData          .git            replicationKumar.Rproj
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to only revert those files, and to do so on the master branch, then you should:

- Check out the master branch
- Check out *only those file(s)* from the previous commit
- Stage the changes (the reverted files)
- Make a new commit

This will look something like the following:

```
git checkout master
git checkout [commit hash] [path/to/file.txt]
...
git add .
git status (does everything look right?)
git commit
```

This will add a new commit to master which reverts the files to their state from the specified old commit. Afterwards you will probably want to run another `git push`.

Comment: I am pretty new to git so maybe I misunderstood the way it works: I thought it was possible to simply go back to a previous commit, but you are saying I should check out those files an commit again. Thus basically I cannot simply step back, correct?

Comment: You can go back to a previous commit, but you would lose any other changes made since that commit (i.e. not just the ones to those files). Is that desirable?

Comment: If so, you need to make the master branch pointer point to an older commit. The command *is dangerous, and will discard all changes you've made in your working directory* [`git reset --hard [commit hash]`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified#id-DZT1HvTEhPUn). The commits you've made since the one specified will still be in the repo, but will no longer be part of the master branch.

Comment: @Dambo - all that said, it is much safer to just move forward as shown in my answer. No weird side effects, just a new commit that changes the files to their old state.

Comment: Ok say I have commits 1,2,3,4. I am now in commit 1, the last. I would like to see my files _as if_ I was in commit 2. You are saying instead that to see everything as if I was in 2, I should either delete 1 or commit 2 to a new commit say '0'. No direct way to just go to commit 2 then?

Comment: @Dambo - I'm confused - do you just want to view the files, recover the files, or completely undo the last commits? Have you made a commit since the files were deleted?

Comment: No commits after deleting those files, however my last commit had those file. I thought that by checking out that commit in which those files existed, they should reappear in my current session (where I have deleted those files).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117765/discussion-between-conduit-and-dambo).